# how to read a specific record from firebase database using golang?

Tags: go, firebase

Database structure:

**user** json:

```
{  
    "-KbF1E26gjZCjPnfcOmi" : {
        "DateOfCreation" : 1485253960222,
        "EmailId" : "abc@gmail.com",
        "FirstName" : "abcd",
        "LastName" : "z z",
        "Status" : "active",
        "UserType" : "admin"
    }
}
```

How to retrieve whole data corresponding to this 
**key(-KbF1E26gjZCjPnfcOmi)**

I have tried this code, but it is not working.

```
func (m *User) RetrieveFromDBId(ctx context.Context,key string)(bool) {
    dB, err := GetFirebaseClient(ctx,"")
    var s []string
    err = dB.Child("User").Child(key).Value(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return false
    }
    log.Println( s)
    return true
}
```

Comment: You are missing the SOF format with all your questions so far.

Answer (score 2):

I got answer

```
func (m *User) RetrieveFromDBId(ctx context.Context,key string)(bool) {

       dB, err := GetFirebaseClient(ctx,"")
       value := User{}
       err = db.Child("/User/"+key).Value(&value)
           if err != nil {
              log.Fatal(err)
              return false
            }
     log.Println( value)
     return true
}
```